# Get element from inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, this

Good morning in my timezone.

i had this code in my HTML page

```
<span id="x>
    <div onclick="$(this).applyFancybox({
        trigger: !$.browser.msie, 
        target: (event.srcElement || event.target)
    }); return false;">
```

And i am changing to this code

```
<span id="x">
    <div>
</span>

<script>
...
$(document).ready (function () {

    $("#x div")
        .click(function(){
            this.applyFancybox({
                trigger: !$.browser.msie, 
                target: (event.srcElement || event.target)
            }); return false;
        });
}
...
</script>
```

This is not working because i think the this is not pointing to the div element, how can i fix it ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: A div in a span is invalid. This is enough to make many operations fail.

Comment: It should point to your div.

Comment: What's event supposed to be ? Didn't you forget to define the parameter of the click callback ?

Comment: Is there a srcElement property on the Chrome event ? I don't think so.

Comment: Unclosed div is invalid too. First step is to get a valid HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

try changing `this` to `$(this)`

`this` is a javascript object and `$(this)` is a jQuery object

So your final code will look like

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#x div")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).applyFancybox({
                trigger: !$.browser.msie, 
                target: (event.srcElement || event.target)
            }); return false;
        });
}
```

By the way , `$.browser.msie` is also deprecated from 1.3 and removed in 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code this might help

```
<span id="x">
    <div>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
...
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#x").click(function(){
        this.applyFancybox({
            trigger: !$.browser.msie, 
            target: (event.srcElement || event.target)
        }); return false;
    });       
}
...
</script>
```

Happy Codings :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/
As of jQuery 1.7, deprecated.
As of jQuery 1.9, removed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event handler `this` points to a `HTMLDivElement` not a jQuery object. There's no such method `applyFancybox`. Try `$(this)`.